Implementing Swap in PCB Project Using Altium
I’m currently adapting an electronic project based on a schematic that was provided to me. Unfortunately, I cannot share parts of the schematic due to confidentiality reasons. However, I have created a diagram that illustrates the issue I’m facing.

In the schematic, there’s a swap being performed, and it’s visually represented as shown in the diagram. I’m using Altium to adapt the design, but I’m struggling to replicate this swap in the software. It seems like a "virtual" component was created to perform the swap. Could that be the case? I’ve researched swap methods online, but I haven’t found anything that matches what I’m seeing. Any guidance on how to implement this in Altium would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Have you followed the instructions in the Altium online guide?

@qrk I took a quick look at the online guide, and I didn't find the swap representation in the schematic in a similar way to what is in the figure.
